# Matching entries using python

Tags: python, parsing, correlation

I have parsed two logs so that just the CVE numbers write into a text file so they appear as one list. here is part of the output;

```
NeXpose Results: CVE-2007-6519
NeXpose Results: CVE-1999-0559
NeXpose Results: CVE-1999-1382
Snort results: CVE-1999-0016
Snort results: CVE-1999-0016
Snort results: CVE-1999-0016
Snort results: CVE-1999-0016
Snort results: CVE-1999-0016
```

and it is like this all of the way through the file. Now I would like to get my code to cipher through the CVE numbers and look if any of the NeXpose CVE's match the snort CVE's as I am looking at correlating the two. Here is my code;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
nexpose = {}
snort = {}

CVE = open("CVE.txt","r")
cveWarning = open("Warning","w")

for line in CVE.readlines():
        list_of_line = line.split(' ')

    if "NeXpose" in list_of_line[0]:
        nexResults = list_of_line[2]
        #print 'NeXpose: ', nexResults



    if "Snort" in list_of_line[0]:
        cveResults = list_of_line[2]
        #print 'Snort: ', cveResults


a_match = [True for match in nexResults if match in cveResults]
print a_match
```

If there is a better way of doing this please let me know as I think I may be overcomplicating things.

Comment: Are you looking for CVEs that appear both as `NeXpose` and as `Snort`?

Comment: the nexpose cve's are pulled from a NeXpose scan report, and the snort cve's are pulled from a snort scan log. and i want to correlate any attacks snort picks up with nexpose vulnerabilities using their CVE numbers.

Comment: So, translating you question to professional terms: You have two collections of CVEs, and you want to know which CVEs appear in both collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered Python sets?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

lines = open('CVE.txt').readlines()
nexpose = set([l.split(':')[1].strip() for l in lines if l.startswith('NeXpose')])
snort   = set([l.split(':')[1].strip() for l in lines if l.startswith('Snort')])

# print 'Nexpose: ', ', '.join(nexpose)
# print 'Snort  : ', ', '.join(snort)

print 'CVEs both in Nexpose and Snort  : ', ', '.join(snort.intersection(nexpose))
```

Comment: you absolute legend bro. cheers for that, really appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to assist. If you intend to continue developing in Python, you might find list comprehension a useful and interesting concept: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using python sets.

```
nex = set()
sno = set()
for line in CVE.readlines():
    list_of_line = line.split(' ')

    if(list_of_line[0]=="NeXpose"):
        nex.add(list_of_line[2])
    if(list_of_line[0]=="Snort"):
        sno.add(list_of_line[2])

inboth = sno.intersection(nex)
```